# finding the length of a function

Tags: calculus

The question is let $f$: [-2, 2] $\rightarrow R $ and $f(x)$=$x^3-x$. find the length f

I know that the length function is $$\int_{-2}^{2} \sqrt{1+(3x^2-1)^2} dx$$

I also know that I should use change of variable and has attempted to let $tan\theta=3x^2-1$, but I still wasn't able to reduce the function to a simpler format, I am wondering if I have done the right change of variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have done the right change of variable. Then you have 
$$\int \sqrt{1+(3x^2-1)^2} dx=\frac{\sqrt3}{6}\int\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}\sec\theta d\theta=\frac{\sqrt3}{6}\int\sec^2\theta d\theta=\frac{\sqrt3}{6}\tan\theta=\frac{\sqrt3}{6}(3x^2-1)$$